# How to jailbreak my iPhone 5c with iOS 8.3?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I have an iPhone 5c with iOS 8.3 and I have been wanting to jailbreak my phone for a long time but I don't know how. I want to do this because I want to get unlimited gems for free on Clash of Clans and so I could get other free stuff on my phone.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing, there is no public jailbreak for iOS 8.3.

Comment: Then do you know of any way that I mod my Clash of Clans game or any way that I can get free gem on Clash of Clans.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely familiar with the technicalities of how this works, but Clash of Clans has an extra payment verification system, as do many popular games, that prevent the conventional in-app purchase bypass from working. You will not be able to get free gems/coins/etc. on Clash of Clans simply by jailbreaking your phone.